# Pygal Module Not Working

Tags: python-3.x, pygal

In trying to run a simple code that has outputs a histogram, I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\tmp\die_visual.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pygal
  File "C:\Users\Christopher\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pygal\__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    from pygal.graph.bar import Bar
  File "C:\Users\Christopher\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pygal\graph\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from .__about__ import *  # noqa: F401,F403
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygal.graph.__about__'
```

I have moved the file that requires pygal to the same directory and I get the same error.

This is the code I have entered.

```
import pygal
from die import Die
# Create a D6.
die = Die()

# Make some rolls, and store results in a list.

results = []
for roll_num in range(1000):
    result = die.roll()
    results.append(result)


# Analyze the results
frequencies = []
for value in range(1, die.num_sides+1):
    frequency = results.count(value)
    frequencies.append(frequency)

# Visualize the results.
hist = pygal.Bar()
hist.title = "Results of rolling one D6 1000 times."
hist.x_labels = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
hist.x_title = "Result"
hist.y_title = "Frequency of Result"
hist.add('D6', frequencies)
hist.render_to_file('die_visual.svg')
```

Comment: Sounds like an installation issue: there is no such import line in the current version of `pygal.graph.__init__.py`.

Comment: Try uninstalling and re-installing pygal through pip.

Comment: Thanks evert. I tried reinstalling python 3.6 and reinstalling all my packages last night and it didn't work. But, I reinstalled pip and then reinstalled pygal this time and everything worked. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

From [pygal site](http://www.pygal.org/en/stable/installing.html):

> Installing
>
> pygal is available for python 2.7 and 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5 and pypy.

Therefore, it's not yet ready for python 3.6.